# Why does this minimization routine work for 2 different samples from the same distribution while the plot only works for one of the 2 samples?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, scipy, distribution, minimize

I am trying to plot a fitted curve to a lognormal dataset. I have two sample datasets. The minimization method works successfully for both datasets, but the plot only works successfully for one. I would like to know why this is so that I can fix it. Below is a quick example.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def from_lognormal_to_gauss(mu, sigma):
    """ 
    Convert parameters from a lognormal distribution to the 
    parameters of the underlying normal distribution. 
    """
    variance = sigma **2
    tmp = variance / mu**2 + 1
    mu_mod = np.log(mu/np.sqrt(tmp))
    sigma_mod = np.sqrt(np.log(tmp))
    return mu_mod, sigma_mod

def initialize_data(sample_success, param_guess='estimate'):
    """ 
    Retrieve sample data and parameter guess.
    """
    if sample_success is True: 
        # this sample works
        mu = 6
        sigma = 0.5
    elif sample_success is False: 
        # this sample minimizes successfully but does not output the correct plot
        mu = 63
        sigma = 7
    x = np.random.lognormal(mean=mu, sigma=sigma, size=1000) # GET LOGNORMAL DATA
    if param_guess == 'estimate':
        param_guess = [np.mean(x), np.std(x)]
        mu_guess, sigma_guess = from_lognormal_to_gauss(*param_guess)
        param_guess = [mu_guess, sigma_guess]
    elif not (isinstance(param_guess, (tuple, list, np.ndarray)) and (len(param_guess) == 2)):
        raise ValueError("as an initial guess, input 2 parameters or input 'estimate'")
    return x, param_guess

## GET PROBABILITY DENSITY FUNCTION (PDF)
pdf_logn = lambda x, mu, sigma : np.exp((-1) * (np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2* sigma**2)) / (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2*np.pi))

## GET NEGATIVE LOG-LIKELIHOOD (NLL)
nll_logn = lambda prms, x : - np.sum(np.log(pdf_logn(x, prms[0], prms[1],)))

def view_plot(x, mu, sigma):
    """ 
    Output plot of fitted curve.
    """
    x = np.array(sorted(x))
    y = pdf_logn(x, mu, sigma)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

As an example of a successful sample run, one can use an initial parameter guess of `[10, 10]`, `[10000000000000, 10000000000000]`, or `'estimate'`.

```
sample_success = True
param_guess = 'estimate'
x, param_guess = initialize_data(sample_success, param_guess)
result = minimize(nll_logn, x0=param_guess, args=(x,), method='Nelder-Mead')
# print(result)
opt_mu, opt_sigma = result.x[0], result.x[1]
view_plot(x, opt_mu, opt_sigma)
```

For an example of the unsuccessful sample run, one can change `sample_success` from `True` to `False` in the code-block just above. The minimization specs for a single run looks like:

```
 final_simplex: (array([[62.95901978,  6.59276009],
       [62.95903676,  6.59281842],
       [62.95908379,  6.59278252]]), array([66263.94460285, 66263.94460285, 66263.94460287]))
           fun: 66263.94460285055
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 102
           nit: 52
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([62.95901978,  6.59276009])
```

Since the `mean` and `sigma` of the underlying normal distribution for the unsuccessful sample are 63 and 7, the minimization works successfully. Since I am using the same algorithm for both samples, I am not sure why the second sample does not plot successfully.

Comment: In the second sample, `x` is between `1e17` and `1e37`, therefore it looks to me like it worked, and the pdf does indeed have values between `1e-21` and `1e-39`.

Comment: Am I wrong to assume `matplotlib.pyplot` automatically scales the axes? Even so, adjusting the y-limits does not produce a visible graph.

Comment: `pdf_logn` is an exponential of some terms divided by `x`. The exponential returns values between `1` and `1e-3` or so, and then you divide it by `x` which in log scale will shift the result of `pdf_logn` 17 below and _add a diference between the values at low `x` and large `x` of 20 orders of magnitude_

Comment: The only way to see such a huge range of different orders of magnitude is in logarithmic scale, `matplotlib` scales the axis, but does not automatically swab between linear and log scale

Comment: If I remember correctly, using log-scaled x-axis creates the illusion of a Gaussian distribution. Though I have yet to play with the y-axis this way. Thanks for the advice, I'll play around with it.

Comment: I have never worked with lognormal distributions, but `matplotlib` is doing the best it can be done in this case. If we restricted to 3 points of your curve only, we would have `[x,pdf_logn(x)]=(1e17,1e-21), (1e27,1e-30), (1e37,1e-39)`, which proportionally is like ploting `(1e-20,1), (1e-10,1e-10), (1,1e-20)`. That is approximately `(0,1), (0,0), (1,0)` because changes of `1e-10` cannot be seen in linear plots, and it is the square corner seen in the plot